# Would the trajectory of a comet be altered by attaching a parachute to it?

Tags: physics, trajectory, engineering, design-alternative, comet

I am curious to know if the trajectory of a comet that is on a collision course for Earth could be altered by simply attaching a parachute to it. The parachute interacting with the comet's tail should slow down the velocity of the comet over a period of time and this should alter its trajectory.

The parachute itself and its cables would have to be made out of a very durable material to handle being within the comet's tail, being constantly bombarded by high-velocity dust particles and water ions.

As far as the particulars of how large the parachute would have to be and how far back from the comet it would have to be is something I have to leave up to aerospace engineers to decide on for I have no expertise in Aerospace. I am asking this question on a conceptual basis simply out of scientific curiosity.

Although it certainly would not be easy sending a crew to the comet's surface (like what was done in the movie *Armageddon*) in order to drill into the comet and attach the cable of the parachute to it, I think this could be a viable solution and it could be a lower-cost alternative to trying to blast it with numerous nuclear missiles.

Would the trajectory of a comet be altered by attaching a parachute to it?

Comment: What about those periods when the comet's "tail" leads the comet?

Comment: @DJohnM, good point. Perhaps the anchor drilled into the comet could have some kind of pivot joint or ball joint so the cable of the parachute could rotate in 360 degrees. Just a thought.

Comment: "very durable material..."  we call that material "unobtanium" for good reason

Comment: Since you're positing that we run a successful intercept mission in the first place, just make your intercept space ship a massive deadload and hit the comet as hard as possible.  That will change its path enough to miss Earth -- assuming your original path prediction is that accurate.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft, first, I think that titanium would be a good choice as a material because it is very heat resistant, second, I think if you want to hit it with a massive deadload than that means a very big and expensive rocket. It that fails to alter its course, do we launch another expensive rocket at the comet? My proposal is low-tech and low-cost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main effect, as far as I can see is that some gas and dust which  escapes from the surface of the comet and is accelerated away from the sun will hit the sail. This should exert a small force away from the sun on the comet, and so yes, it will change its trajectory a little. However, the amount of gas in a comets tail is incredibly tiny. It's visible because it shines in the sunlight, but it's actually a really good vacuum, so the force on the sail will also be tiny (and you don't really need to worry too much about it being damaged by that force either.

If the comet is actually in the process of hitting the Earth, the parachute would exert quite a lot of force in the last second or so, as the comet plunged through the atmosphere, and would probably be destroyed, but this would still not be enough force to stop a comet (typically billions of tons) from hitting.

Comment: @ Steve Linton, I am thinking this parachute would work best on a comet that will first orbit around the Sun before colliding with the Earth rather than a comet hitting the Earth while on its inward path towards the Sun.

Comment: @user255577 That's true, but it's still not going to produce enough thrust to do anything noticeable.

Answer (score 1):

It would, but not in the way you're thinking. From the comet's perspective, the dust doesn't "shoot off" with extreme speeds and generally their orbits are only slightly perturbed by escaping gases. Moreover the amount of mass that comets lose to escaping gas and dust is rather small.

Still, in addition to escaping gases providing small impulses, the sun's light exerts significant amounts of force over long time periods. The parachute, if big enough, could act as a solar sail. Alternatively, you could just paint the comet to change how fast it melts or outgasses.

Answer (score -4):

Ok, so, my first post got deleted because I didn't give enough facts, so now Im giving more facts. First thing to keep in mind is that the tail always points away from the sun, and doesn't come from a fixed point on the comet, it can change if the comet is spinning. Second,there isn't any air in space, so the parachute wouldn't have any effect, since there would be no drag (3 facts right there). If it got into the atmosphere, then the parachute would most likely burn up because of the heat (air molecules cant move out of the way fast enough so it would get super hot and burn up, that's why spaceships have protective layers to not burn up.) (bam, 2 more facts) but lets say it didn't burn up. Then in that case, yes, it would probably change the trajectory in some way if it exited the atmosphere again. The air would catch the parachute, and depending on the size, the drag would differ.(oh yeah more facts) It would most likely slow it down and move it off course a little, but we wouldn't know for sure unless it was actually tested. (bam another fact) So to sum it up, no it wouldn't really affect it that much.

Comment: *Second,there isn't any air in space, so the parachute wouldn't have any effect, since there would be no drag* I believe the OP is asking if a parachute would cause a comet to slow down due to the dust trail or ion tail pushing on the parachute, and in turn, pulling the comet. Similar to how [Solar Sails work.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solar_sail)

Comment: @StarMan, yes, that is what I believe will happen.